# Excel: if Cell has background fill, create copy on another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet where I created a conditional formula where I can search through a range for a given word and if it is a match, The cell will have a background fill. Think of a search bar of sorts.

Is it possible where I can also show the matches in an adjacent cell as well.

For instance I search a range for the word apple. Two matches are then highlighted. Can the matches also be displayed in cells adjacent to the range?

Comment: By matches, I take it you mean indices or something a bit more complex than reprinting "apple"? The problem with the obvious approach is that match() only returns the first match, so you'd not get multiple results.

Comment: Sure, you just mark the range, the formula result shall be applied to and write the formula with the range, where the conditions are in.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be easier to just [filter data](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-data-in-a-range-or-table-7fbe34f4-8382-431d-942e-41e9a88f6a96). I am unsure if what you are trying to get is possible with contidional formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SEARCH function to do this. In the adjacent cells use the formula:

```
=IF(IFERROR(SEARCH($D$5,B3),"")=1,B3,"")
```

[image]

If you want this to get auto-filled whenever you add another row, then add column B and C to a TABLE. That will ensure that when you add another row in B your column C also gets updated.

From your question, it seems that you've also used the SEARCH function. But if not I would recommend to try it in the conditional formatting as well since this identifies the string just like the wildcard *.